# Should a Model interact with external services?

Tags: model-view-controller

**Example 1:**

A Model class "News" stores its text in two different languages (fields: en_text, jp_text). Usually it has text in only one language. Should I translate the text in callback before_save using the Google Translate API, or should I place this code in the Controller?

**Example 2**

A Model class "Payment". When the payment is going to be settled, the system must notify an external service about the successful settling of the payment. Where should this code be placed, Model or Controller?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your Models should be literally the whole business logic of your application. Requirements for your Application mean that you should translate your text or notify some service on payment, don't they? That means that you should write it in your Model.

Controller is an entity that processes request parameters to some business logic actions. Controller should not contain such parts.

As I know, you are using Rails for now, so look at following links (this patterns are also helpful for non-Ruby programmers):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model - classics :)

Comment: Actually I would recommend against use of *active record*, because it pushes domain business logic into the controller. Also, question was bout MVC not MVP.

Comment: @tereško
1) ActiveRecord represents business logic wrapper for database records. ActiveResource is almost the same thing except the fact it wraps external resources.

2) I do not understand you about MVP. I am talking exactly about MVC.

Comment: Yes, you do not understand. That was the point. [Active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) is an antipattern, because, when used, you are unable to separate storage access from domain business logic. You create a structure that is tied to database entities. You end up in situation where domain logic leaks in the controller, because there is no place left in model layer.

Comment: @tereško
Business logic of this particular application implies storing result in database. So I do not agree that ActiveRecord is antipattern in this case. If you are just trying to start holy war about ActiveRecord vs DataMapper then it is not good place to do it. But if you are trying to say that controller should contain this logic then you should just read more about MVC pattern. Controller must never contain it.

Comment: Where did i say that controller **should** contain logic? Please. Point to that line !

Comment: @tereško
Well could you please say WHAT should contain that logic? I was not saying that exactly separate model should be responsible only for translating text. But News model can contain this logic. Also this logic can be separated to some module (adapter for example). But model still has to interact with it.

Comment: Model layer should contain all of the domain business logic. And the view instances should contain all of the presentation logic. Also, model is not a class or an object, but a layer and view is not a template.

Comment: @tereško
Oh, thanks for citation of wikipedia and not giving exact answer for my question. Please reread my answer and you will see that it does not conflict with your comment.

Comment: Which part of it was citation from wikipedia ? And I read what you wrote quite carefully. That was why I started to pick on you =P

Answer (score 0):

The model is usually used to "get" or "set" data, so technically speaking, if your external service provides a service to "get" or "set" data, then yes.